# The module generated by kernel of an elliptic differential operator

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde, differential-operators

Let $D$ be an elliptic  differential operator defined on $\Gamma(E)$  where $\Gamma (E)$  is the space of smooth sections of  vector bundle  $E$ over a smooth manifold $M$. So $\Gamma (E)$ is  a $C^\infty(M)$-module where $C^\infty (M)$  is the space of all smooth functions on $M$.

**Question:** Is it true to say  that the module  generated by $\ker D$ is the whole $\Gamma (E)$?

> **Motvation**: Motivation comes from the method of  variation of parameters in Differential equation. Recall that variation of parameters is based on the following method: we have  a  second order diff. eq. $$y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=g(x)$$(which is  realy an elliptic equation). So we assume that a general solution is in the form $$v_1y_1+v_2y_2$$  where $y_1,y_2$ are solutions of the corresponding homogenious equation $$D(y)=y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0$$ and $v_1,v_2$ are unknown functions. So  for every arbitrary function $h$
> there exist a $y$ in the form  $y=v_1y_1+v_2y_2$  such that $g:=D(h)=D(y)$. This means  that every arbitrary function
> $h$ belongs to the module generated by $\ker D$

**Is there a terminology for those differential operators $D$ for which
$\Gamma(E)$ is equal to the $C^\infty$-module generated by $\ker D$?**

Comment: Take the laplacian on a compact manifold $X$ acting on the space of $p$-forms: the kernel is isomorphic to $H^p(X,\mathbb{R})$, which may very well be zero.

Comment: @abx  Thank you for your  interesting answer. What about a possible counter example in the case of open manifold?

Comment: @AliTaghavi For a non-compact example take $X \times \mathbb{R}^k$ for any $k>0$.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine  I assume you mean $k>1$

Comment: @abx  I wonder  if there is a terminology for those operator $D$ with this property?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Please see my previous comment. your idea is very appreciated.

Comment: @abx  I think you use the fact that every cohomology class has a harmonic representative.

Comment: @abx  So  some other questions naturally arise; what is the  structure of  the  module  generated by harmonic functions on the plane? Does this algebra has a well known structure

Comment: @IgorKhavkine  My previous comment is inspired by your comment above

Comment: Constant functions are harmonic,  they generate everything.

Comment: @abx  So the comment of Igor does not work for $\{pt\}\times \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @abx  anyway I search for some things  non trivial which can be extract from the method of "variation of parameters". I search for a terminilogy or concept about all diff operators with this property.

Comment: @abx  yes you are right the algebra is trivially the whole algebra

Comment: @AliTaghavi Sorry, my comment was intended for the case where some $L^2$-like finiteness condition is imposed on $\Gamma(E)$, which tends to eliminate the kernel of the Laplacian. If the only condition is smoothness, then extending by flat directions does produce more solutions.